# Meaning of "Not me" in The Catcher in the Rye

Tags: meaning, j-d-salinger, the-catcher-in-the-rye

In Chapter 20 of *The Catcher in the Rye*:

> -Why don't you go home, Mac? How old are you, anyway?"
>
> -"Eighty-six.  Listen. Give her my compliments. Okay?"
>
> -"Why don't you go home, Mac?"
>
> -"Not me. Boy, you can play that goddam piano." I told him. I was just
> flattering him. He played the piano stinking, if you want to know the
> truth. ...

What does Holden mean by "Not me"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He means "I'm not going to" essentially. "Who's going home? Not me."